# nginx location match path and everything after it

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I'm tearing my hair out trying to match a location.
I'd like to match something like

```
location ~ /config/<match anything regardless if path, file, or random crap, whether it is there or not> {
"do stuff here"
}
```

I have tried everything I can find online

```
location /config
location /config/
location ~ ^/config/
location ~ ^/config(.*)/(.*)+$ETCETC!!!!ARGHA
```

all attempts just result in 404 errors...

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

location without a prefix is already a prefix match so location /config should work, not location /config/

Comment: yes, that is what I thought too, but it doesn't match:127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018:14:40:28 +0000] "GET /config?_s=pnOArXql-1lgkm8z&_k=Sv-obtaEvKK7vSvM&32 HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/4.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018:14:40:28 +0000] "GET /config/PasteBin?_s=lwHWvuagFEJv58OG&_k=Du4PU9dHs3gtRzw9&57 HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "like"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018:14:40:37 +0000] "GET /config?_s=Qkvk8MFVrJyxS1kW&_k=LGEd9Y6eEUg2ASNM&19 HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "AppleWebKit/525.19"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2018:14:51:40 +0000] "GET /config?_s=jSXg3sdX1Q5ZDO5m&_k=Ih3ug9d6Rjq3GCmG&12 HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "5.0;"

Comment: I should also point out I want to ignore everything after config/, even strip it from the uri

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `~ /config(|/.*)`

seems to work for me :)